# why is this div below the other and not beside it?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to get the yellow div containing 'vending machines | distributors etc' positioned next to the logo (right of the logo). Not sure why it's not working as it's floating left, but for some reason falls below the logo div. Can anybody tell me what mistake I am making?

```css
body{
 background-color:#fff; 
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#header-wrap{
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#BABABA;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #211c20;
 border-top: 1px solid #211c20;
}

#header{
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#72A1D9;
 padding-top:15px;
}

.logo{
 width:130px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-left:50px;
 font-size:24px;
}

.links{
 background:#FFFD00;
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 width:820px;
 font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrap">
    
    <div id="header">

        <div class="logo">LOGO</div>

        <div class="links">VENDING MACHINES | DISTRIBUTORS | SUPPORT | CONTACT</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/n6w2w7yh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class logo has to be float left too, and then your header width is 960 and your logo+links size is superior than 960px (130+50+2+820=1002px)

Correct css is
`

```
#header{
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:#72A1D9;
    padding-top:15px;
}

.logo{
    width:130px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-size:24px;
    float:left;
}

.links{
    background:#FFFD00;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:778px;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

`

Comment: Please use clear:both after using float so user won't get another gap issue. Thanx

Comment: The `.logo` **does not need** `float:left`. One of the things that float does to an element is change it's `display` to `inline-block` and that is the only thing `.logo` needs. The floating itself is useless and can create additional problems (if not cleared).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you are wrong about float, it doesn't turn display, it kills any display (but flex properties) and take elements off of the natural flow, it is more alike an absolute hooked either on the left or the right, that stil use  space for its content , and if previous element is not floatting it first break the line(shift under) https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float

Comment: It actually enforces `display:block`, but it's a very particular case of `display:block`, that behaves exactly like a `display:inline-block`. Technically, I'm wrong, but in practice, I am right. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the logo to `display: inline-block`.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #BABABA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #211c20;
  border-top: 1px solid #211c20;
}
#header {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #72A1D9;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.logo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.links {
  background: #FFFD00;
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 775px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



  <div id="header-wrap">

    <div id="header">
      <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
      <div class="links">VENDING MACHINES | DISTRIBUTORS | SUPPORT | CONTACT</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

1. `.logo` must have float property also
2. The `#header` width is 960px, and logo width is 130 width + 50 padding + 2px from border left and border right = 182px , and width of `.links` is 820px so total is bigger than `#header#` (1002 px).

You need to refine your css, like :

```
.logo{
    width:130px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:50px;
    font-size:24px;
    float:left;
}
```

And

```
.links{
    background:#FFFD00;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:778px +;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
 background-color:#fff; 
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#header-wrap{
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#BABABA;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #211c20;
 border-top: 1px solid #211c20;
        overflow:hidden;
}

#header{
 width:960px;
 height:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#72A1D9;
 padding-top:15px;
}

.logo{
 width:130px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid black;
        text-align:center;
 font-size:24px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
}

.links{
 background:#FFFD00;
 float:right;
 height:50px;
 width:820px;
 font-size:24px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: table;
} 
.links p{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0;
 }
.logo p{
 
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href ="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



<div id="header-wrap">

<div id="header">
<div class="logo"><p>LOGO</p></div>
<div class="links"><p>VENDING MACHINES | DISTRIBUTORS | SUPPORT | CONTACT<p></div>
</div>
</div>
      

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When applying `float` to an element, this element will keep it's original vertical position, in order to achieve what you want using floats, you should apply `float:left` to both `.logo` and `.links` so both will be floated left and stand side by side.

Another solution of course is to use `display:inline-block` to both of them again, but with the usual side effect of having a tiny gap between the two elements if there is a space character between them.

Remember that if you float them both, you may have to [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) the parent so you don't loose its height.